# Cocoa Sandbox: How to get permission to write multiple files or to a directory with NSSavePanel

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox

So the NSSavePanel currently returns a file url complete with extension, and your app has permission to write to that file.

Is there any way to allow the user to select a directory to write to?  For example, if the app is exporting a dozen images at once, the names won't be specified by the user in advance.

Comment: The `NSOpenPanel` is probably the correct way to go. You're asking the user to choose an export location. This has nothing to do with sandboxing, it's just not what `NSSavePanel` is meant for. It's meant for specifying a particular file.

Comment: so how do you get the sandbox to allow the creation of the files once the export location is selected?

Answer (score 7):

You need NSOpenPanel.

```
NSOpenPanel * openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
```